# How do I update MVC 3 Project to jQuery 1.6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, nuget

Using ASP.MVC 3 + Nuget, I've added packages, but this is the first time I've tried to update a package with dependencies. So far, I'm stuck...

Created a brand new ASP.MVC 3 application. Wanted to upgrade jQuery to version 1.6 from the default jQuery 1.5.1.

In the the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> install-package jquery
Successfully installed 'jQuery 1.6'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Conflict occurred. 'jQuery 1.5.1' referenced but requested 'jQuery 1.6'. 'jQuery.vsdoc 1.5.1, jQuery.Validation 1.8.0, jQuery.UI.Combined 1.8.11' depend on 'jQuery 1.5.1'.
```

Is there a different syntax to update a package? Do I need to remove all those dependent packages and re-add them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before updating jQuery to version 1.6, you'll need to upgrade those packages to a version that supports jQuery 1.6.

Comment: Sounds obvious now... ;-) I thought it would update dependencies too. Evidently not. I had to reinstall jquery.vsdoc , jquery.validation , and JQuery.UI.Combined before install-package jquery would work. Thanks!

Comment: Note: on an existing project, you ALSO must update the script src in the _Layout.cshtml file.

Comment: Dependencies are updated but jQuery has none, you meant it doesn't update dependents

Comment: Just to clarify, in the same window where you can update jQuery, select the other packages like jQuery UI Combined, validation,etc. and click Update for each one until they are all updated.  Then try to update jQuery again.

Answer (score 6):

Oh why so complicated? Simply open the `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file and replace:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

after downloading [jquery 1.6](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js) and including it in your `Scripts` folder obviously.

Of course if you are using a CDN (which is what you should by the way if your site is publicly facing) then simply open `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` and replace:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and that's pretty much all you're gonna need.

Comment: Very true. That's what I've always done in the past, but I'm trying to learn how to use the NuGet Package Manager to assist with this task to determine if I'll go that route, or go back to manual updates. Thanks.

Comment: The dependents need to be updated first. Nuget is doing you a favor by telling you that those dependents may not work with 1.6. In particular, jQuery 1.6 has some breaking changes in how the .attr() method behaves and so those dependents may need to release updated versions themselves before you should upgrade to 1.6.

Comment: Jim - you're correct. I'm not too thrilled about the .attr() breaking changes myself. I'm glad this is begin cautious as it will break some of our prior code until we rewrite. Thanks.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but you should avoid using the partial version number in your CDN references. 1.6 is (necessarily) served with a much shorter expires header than 1.6.0.  More info: http://encosia.me/lPrCVT

Comment: Dave: that's a useful off topic post. I've been following your blog for a bit now, so it's cool to see your comment. :-)

Answer (score 2):

NuGet package manager is the proper way to have JQuery upgraded from there, but, so far I didn't see it happen to us. I am using the simple copy and paste way then fix the issue when its popup.

Answer (score 1):

1. in [Add Library Package Reference] and [Installed packages] to remove depend packages.
2. you can install jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to install a package that required a more recent version of jQuery.
I just removed all the packages that were dependent on jQuery and then re installed them one by one. It then allowed me to install my package.